# How to style this mailchimp form for mobile?

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

Hope you're well!

I've just added a sign up form to my website for my MailChimp account.  I want it to

a) display a "your email" text box and the "subscribe" button on one line
b) do the same on mobile, but resize nicely
c) preferably have some padding at the bottom, so it doesn't touch the bottom of the DIV it's in.

Here's the HTML. Let me know if you need anything else!:

```
                        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
                <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                <form action="//scottdaviesdesign.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=6a0182b1b060f7307996ee031&amp;id=26cb77a478" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                   <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                  <div class="mc-field-group">  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your Email"></div>
                <!--</div>-->
                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_6a0182b1b060f7307996ee031_26cb77a478" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="mailchimpbutton"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
                <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

I've had a few tries at it, and just can't get it right at all!

Thanks in advance!
Scott

Comment: Make your own and just use the Mailchimp form actions and IDs

Comment: The form I can manage, it's the styling of it for mobile I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/sqmjstw0/4

Is this want you want? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sqmjstw0/ resize the window to see the different.

```
input[type=email] {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .clear {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .mc-field-group {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Yeah, that's basically it - the only difference is I want the "subscribe" button to be to the left of the "your email address" box.

Comment: Just change the divs in the html code - look at the updated answer.